# Dynamic text completion

Tags: open-ai, chatgpt, question-answering, text-generation

I am using the get_completion function to generate response to a question. Since generating response takes a long time (~5 seconds) I would like to display the response text as it's generated (dynamically, similar to chatgpt or https://www.perplexity.ai/). Does openAI's API make this possible? I couldn't find a code/example anywhere online

Answer (score 1):

That is achieved usually via web-socket, however [it is not available yet](https://community.openai.com/t/need-some-assistance-around-websockets-on-open-ai-api/119851/2)

I see some workaround like https://github.com/cookeem/chatgpt-service, which just get's the full answer and then streams word by word via websocket, so it's even slower

Comment: Please, refrain from answering questions that are off-topic. Instead, you should vote to close them. Programming questions and questions about specific products, tools or APIs are generally off-topic here.